# How to use different target paths after logout?

Tags: security, routes, translation, symfony, logout

Here's my problem: I have a project translated in 2 languages (en & fr). In the security.yml, I've to configure a firewall (with a login form), and specifically the target path after logout:

```
logout:
    path: /user/logout
    target: /
```

But I can't choose the target path depending on user's culture...

I don't have this problem when signin, in fact I choose the target path directly in my login form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/{{ app.session.locale }}/" />
```

So I don't know how to redirect after logout on /fr/ if you are french, or otherwise /en/ ... Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom logout handler, see `successHandler` property of [`Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\LogoutListener`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/LogoutListener.php). With the DIC you can easily override it.

Comment: It will be highly useful for beginners to detail this answer. It is a solution to a important issue. Another use case is when we have different versions of target page (Mobile and Desktop). Thanks in advance